# Can we have more JNDI resources defined in a spring boot project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jndi

I am trying to port an application to use JNDI data sources and the context.xml contains 9 Resource tags, so 9 different database names and URLs.

I modified context.xml by adding ResourceLinks and server.xml with all resources, but how can I create a jndi properties file where I could have all the names of the databases ? If I try to add more than one, it tells me that I have duplicate key.

Is what I am trying to do possible? If yes, how can I mention all of them in the properties file?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-persistence-jpa-jndi-datasource can you check here first.

Comment: This is the link that helped me until now, it only mentions one database

Comment: Just change the name for the resources